# XML elements does not properly nest inside foreach

Tags: c#, xml

Just wrote a web service and try to return columns of a sharepoint list as xml. But items are not properly nesting

```
            System.Xml.XmlNode node = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Inventories"));
            foreach (ListItem item in items)
            {
                node = node.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Inventory"));
                node.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("ID")).InnerText = Convert.ToString(item["ID"]);
                node.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Name")).InnerText = Convert.ToString(item["Server_Name"]) + " >> " + Convert.ToString(item["Computer_Name"]) + " >> " + Convert.ToString(item["IP"]);
            }
        }
            return doc.InnerXml;
```

This one returns

```
<inventories>
  <inventory>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
  </inventory></inventory></inventory>
</inventories>
```

So the inventory items inside foreach loop act a bit of weirdo, I just want it to be a parent for each ID and Name attribute but did not figure out what am I doing wrong.

Has to be something like that

```
<inventories>
  <inventory>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
  </inventory>
  <inventory>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
  </inventory>
</inventories>
```

All helps will be appreaciated and thanks all of you for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reusing the name "node" try:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode rootNode = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Inventories"));
System.Xml.XmlNode childNode;
            foreach (ListItem item in items)
            {
                childNode =doc.CreateElement("Inventory");
                childNode .AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("ID")).InnerText = Convert.ToString(item["ID"]);
                childNode .AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Name")).InnerText = Convert.ToString(item["Server_Name"]) + " >> " + Convert.ToString(item["Computer_Name"]) + " >> " + Convert.ToString(item["IP"]);
                rootNode.AppendChild(childNode);
            }
        }
        return doc.InnerXml;
```